# Client side pre-save Javascript hook on all admin pages

Tags: javascript, hooks, admin

I'm planning a Wordpress plug-in and new to the process. I have read about admin filters and actions which get executed server side. Is there any way of intercepting admin page submits globally on the client side, before the submit is actioned? I would like to run some Javascript code prior to the submit and then carry on with the original submit request. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

By submit I mean send data to the server usually for saving. I.e. the user presses 'save' etc in an admin page. I'd like to hook into EVERY client side admin page 'save' before the data is sent.

Comment: What do you mean by "submit"? "Publish"? "Save options"?

Comment: By submit I mean send data to the server usually for saving. I.e. the user presses 'save' etc in an admin page. I'd like to hook into any client side admin page 'save' before the data is sent.

Comment: Why didn't you include that information in your question? [Edit the question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/349673/edit)